# Spring Data ElasticSearch (Specifying types in search requests is deprecated)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Elastic Search beginner here.

When performing a `.findAll()` operation through a `ProviderRepository` that extends `ElasticsearchRepository`, I'm seeing the warning below.

```
2020-11-19_17:31:09.218 WARN  org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient - [::] request [POST http://mysearch:9200/provider_search/provider/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.6.2-ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f "[types removal] Specifying types in search requests is deprecated."]
```

I do not want the /provider/ part in the URL. If I paste the URL without the /provider/ part, I can get the desired response. /provider/ part causes the request to return with 0 results. However, I'm not sure where the /provider/ part gets appended to the URL.

Here's my Repository

```
public interface ProviderRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Provider, Long> {
}
```

Here's the Entity/Document

```
@Document(indexName = "provider_search")
public class Provider {

     private Long id;

     private String providerName;

    ...
}
```

And, here's my config

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(
    basePackages = { "com.commons.repositories.elastic" })
public class ElasticDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("mysearch:9200")
            .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

**Tl;dr**
Need help removing /provider/ part from the aforementioned URL.

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use? And which version is your Elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: SpringData Elastic search is 4.1.1. Cluster version is 7.6.2 and I also have elasticsearch: version 7.10.0

Answer (score 0):

I had to update Spring Boot version from 2.2.* to 2.3.* to get it working. For some reason, the embedded transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter-data was messing with my direct elasticsearch dependency. Even when I installed 4.0.* spring-data-elasticsearch, the transitive dependencies within spring-data-elasticsearch were in 6.* versions. Once, I updated Spring Boot, all of the transitive dependencies of spring-data-elasticsearch (version 4.0.*) changed from 6.* to 7.*.